# Storing captured image into SQlite Database? (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

So far I have got the camera api working for my app, to which the camera is opened when a button is clicked and once the image is taken it is displayed on the page.

My next step is to store the image into my sqlite database within a table. Creating the database is no problem as I already have a couple of other tables used for other parts of the app which work fine, it's just finding out how to store the image into the database.

Can someone provide some assistance here?

Camera Function:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.getElementById("btnCamera").onclick = function() {
     navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageUri) {
     var lastPhotoContainer = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
     alert("Hot stuff!");
     lastPhotoContainer.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageUri + "' style='width: 75%;' />";
     }, null, null);
          };
          }
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page7" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Sign ut</a>
        <h1>SoccerMeet</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <input id="btnCamera" type="button" value="Camera photo" />
        <p id="lastPhoto"></p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>&copy; Gallery</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED Script:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  var db;

  function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Gallery (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myImage BLOB)');
    }, errorE, successS);
  }

  function successS() {
    alert("Camera database ready!");
    document.getElementById("btnCamera").onclick = function() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
      });
    };
  }

  function onSuccess(tx, imageData) {
    alert("Camera test 1");
    var image = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    base64imageData = imageData;
    var _Query3 = ("INSERT INTO Gallery(myImage) values ('" + base64imageData + "')");
    alert(_Query3);
    tx.executeSql(_Query3);
  }
  /*   function successCamera() {
     navigator.notification.alert("Image has been stored", null, "Information", "ok");
       $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
   } */

  function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
  }

  function errorE(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
  }
```

Comment: You convert the image to base64 and store it .

Comment: @IamKarim1992 would be great if you could provide some sort of template?

Comment: @Mahdi : Have you got the solution for your query? As I am also facing issues in similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.getElementById("btnCamera").onclick = function() {
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 });
 };
          }
          function onSuccess(imageData){
           var image = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
           image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
           //the imageData is a base64 representation of the image.
           base64imageData=imageData;// this variable is a global variable and when ever asked for u can send it to SQL Operation class for storing.
          }

          function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I'm still not fully aware of how I can insert the data into the database. I have updated my code to show in full extent how it looks, I've created another query that creates a new table called gallery as you can see above. Could I possible throw in a execute sql to insert '"+ image.src + "' into the "myImage" column?

Comment: you make a query and pass it .tx.executeSql(sql); where var sql = "INSERT INTO Gallery (id, myImage ) VALUES("SomeID",'" + (base64imageData) + "')"....where u decalared base64imageData as global variable which will be accesible to the db write function , which u would call wherever u like. This is the logic and a very valid answer as i implemented it . If it helps mark it as an answer.

Comment: no u cannot as img.src is local to the success function but base64imageData would be global and u can access the data any where u run the tx.executeSql

Comment: I've updated my code again. I am getting the query alert, which says undefined for the base64imageData. I have put brackets around it and without, both times i get undefined.